# Return the previous index in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, foreach

I have a For Each loop that is looping through an array of strings to find the first string with a length of three characters. For example, when looping through the array, if the first 3 character string is the 4th index of the array, I would like for it to return the 3rd (previous) index of the array. Any help would be appreciated.

```
For Each piece As String In p
        If piece.Length = 3 Then
            'Return previous index
        End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

If `p` is a collection accessible by index (ie: `IList(Of T)`), you can switch to a For loop, and return the element at the current index -1.

Otherwise, you can keep the previous item in a separate variable, and return it when your condition is met.

```
Dim lastItem as String
For Each piece As String In p
    If piece.Length = 3 Then
        Return lastItem ' Will return Nothing if this is the first item...
    End If
    lastItem = piece ' Store this for next time
Next
```

Comment: Very simple and straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To p.Count - 1
        If p(i).Length = 3 Then
            'Return previous index
            Return p(i - 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Note the loop will have to start at 1 (not zero) otherwise you could return the (0-1)th element of the array which won't exist

Comment: +1 for a different perspective than above. I am rather new to this so different ideas are always a positive way of learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.FindIndex`, if you have a `List(Of T)`:

```
Dim i As Integer = p.FindIndex(Function(x) x.Length = 3)

If i > 0 Then
    Dim previous As String = p(i - 1)

    'Do something
End If
```

If you have a `String()`, you can also use the `Array` version:

```
Array.FindIndex(Of String)(p, Function(x) x.Length = 3)
```